# FrameLayout: is it possible to put child layout off-screen?

Tags: android, xml, android-framelayout

is it possible to have structure like the one below.
And have LinearLayout that is at front to be off screen:

```
<FrameLayout>

   <LinearLayout>
   .. Back Layout
   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout>
   .. Front layout
   </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Here is the image.[image]
What I have tried: 
I have tried setting android:layout_marginLeft="-300dp" for LinearLayout A (front), but as soon as I test it on my phone the A layout is back inside of visible area. 
I have also tried pushing the A layout off the screen with TranslateAnimation, after animation ends A layout is back inside of visible area.

Please help me solve the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want it offscreen and not simply hidden?

Comment: I'm trying to have a slide menu, but it should be on top of B layout. so it wouldn't push B to the right. I'm still experimenting with scrollTo().

Comment: Have a look at the SlidingMenu library.

Comment: I would like to the SlidinMenu library, but it's not working the way I need it, and changing the library to fit my needs is too difficult for a newbie like me. I will look into the lib's code though, because it's fun. Thank you guys for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in case anyone needs something like this here how I solved it. 
Sliding menu on top of content. 
Layout structure as described in the question. Here is a simple animation in xml:
show_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-100%" 
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:duration="400">
    </translate>
</set>
```

hide_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%" 
        android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:duration="400">
    </translate>
</set>
```

in MyActivity

```
//loading hide animation and setting listener.
anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.hide_menu); 
    anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        //on animation end setting visibility to gone
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            MenuList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Same thing is done for animation for show_menu animtaion except it would have onAnimationStart setting visibilty to visible. 
MenuList in the code is A layout from the figure in the question.

**Update:**
**The best way to do a sliding menu today is to use the DrawerLayout.**