# How to arrange Layout and which layouts to use for FB menu like effect

Tags: android, android-layout

I have three controls arranged vertically, List View, Menu Button and Hidden Menu.
List view will occupy the whole screen and menu button will be stick to the bottom of the screen. When we touch menu button, hidden menu will slide up and will occupy the almost half screen. Hidden menu will not cover the whole screen.

What layouts can I use and how to arrange?

Added Extra Info.

Below is my test xml layouts. If I send off-screen for my sub menu, the list data is not loaded, i think it's because it's not displayed on screen.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header_layout"
        android:background="#ffffff" >

        <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/listview_Category"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="500dp"
                android:divider="#E5E5E5"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:background="#aaaaaa"
                tools:listitem="@layout/list_item"
                >
            </ExpandableListView>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButtonMenu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:src="@drawable/menu_icon" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listview_Cat"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="500dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButtonMenu"
                android:background="#777777"
                android:divider="#ffffff"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:translationY="500dp"
                tools:listitem="@layout/category_list_item" >
            </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use This https://github.com/i8ramin/fb-menu

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16338647/framelayout-is-it-possible-to-put-child-layout-off-screen

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Frame Layout  in which the list view covers the whole layout and the menu button is bottom aligned and the menu has a fixed width and height...

but since it is a sliding menu you are looking for you can also use **Navigation Drawer** introduced in the latest version of android.

Comment: Below is my sample xml layouts ,,, "listview_Cat" is the hidden menu. When I set its possition off screen, list data is not loaded. e.g. toEndOf.